# Hazelcast: how data is partitioned when using Cluster Groups?

Tags: hazelcast

In the Hazelcast docs it is stated about **Cluster Groups**:

> You can create cluster groups. To do this, use the group configuration element.
>
> By specifying a group name and group password, you can separate your clusters in a simple way. Example groupings can be by development, production, test, app, etc. <...> Each Hazelcast instance can only participate in one group. Each Hazelcast instance only joins to its own group and does not interact with other groups.
>
> <...>
>
> The cluster members (nodes) and clients having the same group configuration (i.e., the same group name and password) forms a private cluster.
>
> Each cluster will have its own group and it will not interfere with other clusters.

But there are no details about data partitioning.

If I have 5 nodes and 2 cluster groups:

- node1, node2 and node3 are members of GroupA
- node4 and node5 are members of GroupB

does it means that no data from GroupA will be stored at nodes4 and node5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that's what it means. Those groups are independent clusters and have nothing in common (except maybe the network ;-)).

If you look for data partitioning, Hazelcast distributes information based on keys but you can have some kind of influence by utilizing data affinity (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#data-affinity).

If you're looking for backup distribution you might be interested in partition groups (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#partition-group-configuration).

Comment: can you create client-only members for a cluster, where no data is stored? how do you separate app and hazelcast jvms separately?

Comment: You can configure a member as lite-member. In this case no data partitions are assigned to that specific member. However you're still able to address it for operations with the ExecutorService. For pure data access I'd always recommend to use a real Hazelcast client over a lite member.